# AS3: invalid Bitmap

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am trying to run the following function where `car` is a movieclip:

```
public function cacheCar():void
{
car.bounded = new Rectangle(car.getBounds(car));
var carOffset:Matrix = car.transform.matrix;
carOffset.tx = car.x - car.bounded.x;
carOffset.ty = car.y - car.bounded.y;

car.bmpData = new BitmapData(car.bounded.width,car.bounded.height,true,0);
car.bmpData.draw(car, carOffset);
}
```

but I am recieving the following error:

> ArgumentError: **Error #2015: Invalid BitmapData**.   at
>   flash.display::BitmapData/ctor()  at flash.display::BitmapData()  at
>   com.George.MegaAmazingApp.Components::Road/cacheCar()
>   [C:\path\to\class\called\Road.as:55]

Line 55 is:     `car.bmpData = new BitmapData(car.bounded.width,car.bounded.height,true,0);`

Can anyone see why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either width or height for the `BitmapData` is returning 0. Try getting the bounds using the stage: `car.bounded = car.getBounds( car.stage );`

On a side note, `getBounds()` returns a `Rectangle` so you don't need to create a new one.